# org-mode function to check checkbox and move to next in list?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In Emacs org-mode, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> runs `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`, which, on a checkbox `[ ]`, changes its state to `[X]`. But it also leaves the point where it was, in the now-checked checkbox.

Is there a command that changes the checkbox state, then jumps to the NEXT checklist item?

Even better, is there a single keybinding that changes the state of EITHER a checkbox or a `TODO`, depending on where the point is, then jumps to the next checkbox or `TODO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any built-in command that will do so, however you can combine the commands for `org-toggle-checkbox` and `org-next-item` (with a quick check to ensure it is a checkbox) to get the desired behaviour.

```
(defun zin/org-checkbox-next ()
  (interactive)
  (when (org-at-item-checkbox-p)
    (org-toggle-checkbox))
  (org-next-item))
```

There may be a way to also deal with TODO entries, however it would be more error prone since it would not stop at the end of a list/level of headlines.

Comment: Amazing. And how to bind this function to `C-c C-c` when in a checkbox item?